# Multilinear Interpolation for unknown number of points in n dimensions

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, interpolation

I'm currently trying to create a method which can make a multilinear interpolation for an unknown number of points (the number is equal to 2^n) in n-dimensional space.

The cases for n = 1 (no interpolation) and n = 2 (linear interpolation) are already implemented and seem to work. But now I'm already struggling to make the bilinear interpolation (for the case n = 4) dimension agnostic and I have no idea how I should progress from that point on (n = 8, ..., 2^n).

Is there a general approach for this problem or should I hardcode some of the cases and throw an UnsupportedOperationException otherwise?

Below I added an SSCCE which should hopefully clarify my problem. It consists of a point class which stores the coordinates and a value and also contains some functionality like calculating the distance to another point and the interpolation method which already contains my implementation of the cases for n = 1 and n = 2.

### Code

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Interpolator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interpolator ip = new Interpolator();

        Point currentPoint = new Point(new long[]{5, 5}, 0);

        List<Point> neighbors = new ArrayList<Point>() {{
            add(new Point(new long[]{3, 3}, 7));
            add(new Point(new long[]{10, 10}, 4));
        }};

        System.out.println(ip.interpolate(currentPoint, neighbors));
    }

    public float interpolate(Point currentPoint, List<Point> neighbors) {

        if (neighbors.size() == 1) {
            // no interpolation necessary with only one neighbor
            return neighbors.get(0).getValue();
        } else if (neighbors.size() == 2) {
            // distance between point and the two neighbors
            float distanceOne = currentPoint.distance(neighbors.get(0));
            float distanceTwo = currentPoint.distance(neighbors.get(1));
            float completeDistance = distanceOne + distanceTwo;

            // calculate weights
            float weightOne = 1 - distanceOne / completeDistance;
            float weightTwo = 1 - distanceTwo / completeDistance;

            // linear interpolation
            return neighbors.get(0).getValue() * weightOne
                    + neighbors.get(1).getValue() * weightTwo;
        } else if (neighbors.size() == 4) {
            //TODO: bilinear interpolation
        } else if(neighbors.size() == 8){
            //TODO: trilinear interpolation
        }

        //TODO: quadlinear interpolation or higher?
        return -1;
    }

    public static class Point {

        private long[] m_coordinates;
        private float m_value;

        public Point(final long[] coordinates, float value) {
            this.m_coordinates = coordinates;
            this.m_value = value;
        }

        public long[] getCoordinates() {
            return this.m_coordinates;
        }

        public int numDim() {
            return m_coordinates.length;
        }

        public long dim(final int i) {
            return this.m_coordinates[i];
        }

        public float distance(final Point otherPoint) {
            if (this.numDim() != otherPoint.numDim()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Can't measure distance between points with different dimensionality");
            }

            float sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.numDim(); i++) {
                sum += Math.pow(this.dim(i) - otherPoint.dim(i), 2);
            }

            return (float) Math.sqrt(sum);
        }

        public float getValue() {
            return m_value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what your algorithm does but is dimension agnostic. I am not saying your calculation is correct - I am just saying that I think this is the same calculation but for *n* dimensions:

```
public float interpolate(Point currentPoint, List<Point> neighbors) {
  int dimensions = neighbors.size();
  float[] distance = new float[dimensions];
  float sumDistances = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
    distance[i] = currentPoint.distance(neighbors.get(i));
    sumDistances += distance[i];
  }
  float[] weight = new float[dimensions];
  for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
    weight[i] = 1 - distance[i] / sumDistances;
  }
  float interpolatedDistance = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
    interpolatedDistance += neighbors.get(i).getValue() * weight[i];
  }
  return interpolatedDistance;
}
```

Comment: I doubt that it is the correct strategy to calculate the distances.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr - Please explain. This is the same algorithm as OP used but generalised to n dimensions.

Comment: I expressed myself incorrectly, sorry, and I should have made my comment at the question, not at your answer. I meant to say that I doubt that it is the correct strategy for multilinear interpolation, because it uses the distances, instead of using the content sizes of rectangles, cubes, etc or doing a step-by-step method as explained in wikipedia (e.g. for trilinear interpolation). In other words, I agree with your text "I am not saying your calculation is correct" :-)